# Jquery toggle selected items from multiple selectable lists (except the current selection) on selecting any of the items from either of the lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am attempting to use two selectable lists with the same selectable class, I want to toggle all the items irrespective of the parent list when a selection is made.

Currently when I select an item, only the selections from the same list get toggled/unselected, but the selected item from the other list remains selected.

Is there any way to have these as two separate lists but behave as the same one, for this specific function?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

```js
$( ".selectable" ).selectable();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    
<style>
    div {border:1px solid black;}
    .selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
    .selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
    .selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; width: 60%; }
    .selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
</style>
    
    <div id="div1">
        <h4>List 1</h4>
        <ul class="selectable">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
            <li>Item 7</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div id="div2">
        <h4>List 2</h4>
        <ul class="selectable">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
            <li>Item 7</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: The `$( ".selectable" ).selectable();` implies your a using a jquery-plugin. Where are the docs for that plugin?

Comment: @styfle Here is the [link](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable) for the docs

Comment: I added the jquery-ui tag and made your code a runnable snippet. Do you care if the answer is actually two html lists (two `ul`) or can they be the same list with a visual separator?

Comment: They could be one list, but I will need to have two headers and two positions on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose what I was trying to achieve here is what is defined under a different widget, you would call menu.

Changing the script to:

```
$(".selectable").menu();
```

gave the desired result.